# WiFiSSLClient will not connect to servers with LetsEncrypt certificates

Tags: wifi, mkr1000

I'm trying to send data from an Arduino program to an app running on Google App Engine but `WiFiSSLClient.connect()` always returns false.

This is despite

- the server being up and running;
- the code working when the web app was on a different server.

The only possible explanation I can come up with is that the App Engine app uses a `LetsEncrypt` certificate while the other server was using one by another company.

```
WiFiSSLClient client;
if (client.connect(server, 443)){
    // Connected to server
} else {
    // Failed to connect
}
```

Does anyone have any solutions to this problem? I had a look at `WiFiClientSecure`; it has the ability to set the CA certificate in code but this seems like a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to update the certificates the WIFI 101 Firmware Updater tool (in the Arduino IDE).

1. Install the `FirmwareUpdater` sketch, as described on the [Arduino site](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/FirmwareUpdater).
2. Select *Tools -> WiFi 101 Firmware Updater*. Click on the *Add domain* button at the bottom, enter your domain and click *Upload Certificates to WiFi module*.
   [image: Adding a new domain]
3. Upload the sketch to your Arduino. It should now connect to the server.